# What does this class do?-Python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand what does this class

```
class undo:
    def __init__(self, ss):
        self.ss = ss
```

In my head it should simply put the value of ss uniquely in the variables i decide to use,but when I'm using it it rewrites all the variables, as if it was shared.

```
sum_expenses[100][0] = 100
sum_expenses[99][2] = 99

s = 1
a = [0 for i in range(100)]
a[s] = undo(sum_expenses)
output(a[1].ss)

sum_expenses[100][0] = 0
b = undo(sum_expenses)
print " "
print b.ss
print " "
sum_expenses[99][2] = 1
a[2] = undo(sum_expenses)
print a[2].ss
```

I do not understand why it overwrites all the variables with the current values of sum_expense, when I try to put it individually so that I can use the past values of sum_expenses.

Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you're giving `__init__` a reference to the list. If you change the list somewhere else, the reference in `.ss` still points to the same list, so the changes are visible there, too.

You could copy the list, since it's 2D try [`deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you call this function it overrides reference to thr whole array ss, changing it to the new one you just passed to the constructor.

You can also create this array within the class and pass indexes and value to it like so:

```
undo.add(index1,index2,value)
```

Or you can make another variable ss_old and have make the function return that variable before you set it to a new value.